# Stuck on some multichoice questions for MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I was doing some past year test on `MYSQL` questions and I am not sure of the following questions. Can someone help me out?

My picks for the following questions are as follows but I'm not sure if they are right:

```
4c
```

[image]

Comment: People got time for negative votes but not answering questions. Wow.

Comment: I'd go with 4c, 6a, 21b, 12d - but I'm only guessing. And down-voting is quick and fun.

Comment: @Strawberry which ones are you sure of completely?

Comment: I suppose I'm confident of all except for 12

Comment: Thank you! Answer the question and ill tick you for the correct answer =D if you want just dont include the answer for 12 in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 4c

Add another column and you'll get the error

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

a) Doesn't matter as long as you don't want to insert duplicate keys

b) Data will get truncated and a warning is produced, but not a fail

d) Not true, you can specify whatever value you want (as long as it's not a duplicate **if** the column is primary key or has an unique index on it)

e) Why should it break. You don't have to have a PK, though I'd strongly recommend to have one.

---

### 6a

c, d and e are not unique, of course. Difference between a and b is, in b district is not needed to make it unique. Would it be good to have district in the automatically created index for primary keys? No. If you want to improve performance of queries on this table, one can assume that almost every field of this table is in the where clause. Therefore you want to have a compound index and in this, you want to have the columns first, that filter the most rows. And this most certainly is neither country, nor district.

---

### 21b

Not much to say about that, it's pretty clear.

---

### 12d

The most difficult part about this question is how to interpret the sentences given. Sure thing is though, that the foreign key as defined makes sure, that you can not insert a value into A.X when there's no corresponding value in B.Y. This makes B the parent table, so I'd go with "from B to A". And it's a 1:N relation, that's clear.